# Iron man Jarvis like robot

Tags: mobile-robot, quadcopter, microcontroller, mechanism, embedded-systems

I'm very passionate about robots from my childhood.I'm a java developer.
I love sci-fi movies.I have a little bit knowledge in embedded systems and electronics.
My ambition is to build a robot like Jarvis (In Iron Man Movie).Which is a voice controlled robot.I would like to implement that in my house as a home automation system.It would take voice as input and take appropriate action.. Please help me to do this. 
Any kind of help is appreciated..

Comment: I hate to bust your balls (welcome to Robotics.SE by the way), but your question is similar to this: "I love helping people and I want to become a doctor. I have a little bit of knowledge about livers and the pancreas. Please help me become a heart surgeon". In other words, this question is way too broad to be properly answerable. There are many aspects to building a complex robot such as mechanics, electronics, hardware, software, even materials and each with various sub-topics. You would almost always need a _team_ to build a complex robot like that.

Comment: where i start . Please help me to find any kind of speech recognition systems..

Comment: If I ask "where do I start" for my heart surgeon analogy, what would you answer? The same answer goes for your question.

Comment: Try this out: http://api.ai/
...and good luck for your dream :)

Comment: 1. Find a cheap robot arm, 2. Learn Python, 3. Get a voice-to-text program on a computer 4. program a python program to take text input (translated from voice by #3), to issue commands to the arm. You won't have any sensing, it won't be intelligent, it will be very simple, but it'll work. Now, this question will be closed because it is too broad and not helpful to future readers, but I loved it so I answered it the best I could here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has already been pointed out, this is such a broad topic, it's almost impossible to answer it... People do entire doctoral thesis for years on "just" one aspect like speech recognition!!

But here is what you could do:

1) get a Raspberry Pi for the brain. You'll have to learn how to use Linux and a programming language like Python

2) get a cheap robotic arm: [this one](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/robotic-arm-kit-with-usb-pc-interface-a37jn) has been reverse-engineered before and you can find all the code on the web to control it with the raspberry pi

3) add a microphone and a little speaker and use the google Speech API for voice recognition

When you get there, you'll be where most hobbyist can get too easily without needing a lab or expensive equipment. Many people have done very similar projects, just google it, look on YouTube.